# Using ThreadPool to Upload Files on S3 via AWS SDK

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-s3, threadpool

I am trying to upload files to S3, to improve performance I am trying to spawn a threadpool of 100 threads to execute this task however when I trigger my console application it just stops executing once I run it and breaks.

This is what I tried so far,

```
string bucketName = <<bucket-name>>;
var threadCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(100, 100);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((obj) =>
{
  UploadFile(bucketName);
}));

public void UploadFile(string bucketName)
    {
        TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest uploadDirectoryRequest;           

        string directoryName= @"D:\Files\100KB";
        
        try
        {
            uploadDirectoryRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Directory = directoryName,
                KeyPrefix = "upload_dir",
                UploadFilesConcurrently = true
            };

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();                
            
            transferUtility.UploadDirectory(uploadDirectoryRequest);
            
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time Elapsed:"+stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);                
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }

    }
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong with respect to using the threadpool? What would be the correct way to write this logic?

Comment: What kind of performance issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: @SirRufo I am trying to compare the performances of both transfer utility and putobject s3 uploads against varying data sizes (256KB-2MB)

Comment: Some thoughts on threads here: uploads are IO bound and do not need to use threads. ThreadPool settings affect the whole application